# Overcome typescript type error using ramda groupby

Tags: typescript

I don't know how to fix this typescript error. I'm trying to use ramda's groupBy function:

```
245: const groups = R.groupBy((row: Record) => {
246:            return row[this.props.groupBy]
247:        })(this.props.data)
```

Where this.props.groupBy is defined as :

```
groupBy?: {[K in keyof Record]}
data: Array<Record>
```

The error that I get is:

```
Error:(245, 38) TS2345:Argument of type '(row: Record) => <T>(obj: any) => T' is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: Record) => string'.
  Type '<T>(obj: any) => T' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Error:(246, 31) TS2683:'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.
```

EDIT: I decided not to struggle with the keyof type and just declared it a groupBy as a string. I don't think these were my real errors, but intellij was having trouble updating its error messages, so who knows. They've gone away now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems in your question, fixing got the code to work easily:

```
namespace X {

    class Record {
        Test: string;
        Bla: string;
        test: number;
    }

    class TT {
        props: {
            groupBy?: keyof Record,
            data: Array<Record>
        }
        name() {
            const groups = R.groupBy((row: Record) => {
                return row[this.props.groupBy].toString();
            })(this.props.data)
        }
    }
}
```

The problems were :

1. `groupBy` should be a `keyof Record` not `{[K in keyof Record]}`. The first one defines a type that can take any name of the properties of `Record`. Your version defined a type that has the same structure as `Record` but with all properties of type any.
2. `groupBy` specifically wants the return type to be a string, while the indexing operation on `row` can return any type of the properties of record (ex `string|number` in the example above) You should do a `.toString` to convert everything to string

**Note:** I used standard compiler settings, you might get other errors with `strict` but since don't mention the options I assumed standard. I tested with TS 2.6.2, and latest typings for Ramda from npm, other versions may differ in the errors.

Answer (score 0):

> Overcome typescript type error using ramda groupby

You can use a type assertion to `any`:

```
245: const groups = (R as any).groupBy((row: Record) => {
246:            return row[this.props.groupBy]
247:        })(this.props.data)
```

## More

- Type assertion: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html

Comment: I'm not sure why you he should for `R` to be any, there are type definitions for this library, he probably is doing something else wrong.